# PHP-Using $this->db->get()->result() in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm trying to create a web page that when user click on the below link,it will bring user to the next page

`<a href="../try/sewcutrptsummary?pro={$row ->idmsul}" target="blank"">Link`

My question is,how can i retrieve the same data from 1st page & display it in a textbox in 2nd page as shown in below pictuce?

[Retrieve data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e3LiO.png)

This is the view for the 2nd page

```
<div class="control-group">
<label for="proid" class="control-label">MSUL ID</label>
<div class="controls"> 
 <input type="text" id="txtinput" name="txtinput"value="">
<select id="prodtype" name="prodtype"onchange="checknumber();">
<option selected >--Select Product Type--</option>
 <option value="Main"  >Main</option>
 <option value="Sub">Sub</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="controls" id="after" style="display : none">         
<select id="cutprod" name="cutprod" class="input-xxlarge">
</select>

<input id="generatebtn" type="button" class="btn-primary btn-small" onclick="generateRpt();" value="Generate" ></div>
</div>
```

and this is the controller

```
function index() {
        $this -> smarty -> assign("page", "View Cutting Report Summary");
        $this -> smarty -> assign("dataname", "Cutting Report Summary");
        $this -> smarty -> assign("pagename", "sewcutrptsummary");
        $this -> smarty -> assign("msg", "");
        $this -> smarty -> assign("script", "Yes");

        $idmsul = $this -> input -> get_post("pro");
        $query = "Select idmsul from sindi_schedule where idmsul='{$idmsul}' group by idmsul";
        $result = $this -> global_model -> query($query) -> result();
        $data['idmsul'] = $result;

        $this -> smarty -> view('sewcutrptsummary.tpl',$data);
        }
```

Can anybody assist me on this problem?

Your help is greatly appreciate.

Comment: What are you asking ? Its totally unclear

Comment: The question is actually quite clear, especially with the provided image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple pass the data `pro` to view like this

**In controller :**

```
.....
$data['idmsul'] = $result;
$data['id'] =$this->input->get_post("pro"); //here pass the id to view 
$this->smarty->view('sewcutrptsummary.tpl',$data);
....
```

**In view :**

```
<input type="text" id="txtinput" name="txtinput" value="{$id}">
```

Comment: i try to do as you say,but  it display this in the textbox                                 
 <?php  if(isset($id)){ echo $id; }  ?>

Comment: Try this `<input type="text" id="txtinput" name="txtinput" value="{$id}">` @Dn91

Answer (score 0):

You are passing the data as a query string, therefore the following should work

```
if(isset($_GET["pro")) {  // Safeguard in case value is not there
    $pro = $_GET["pro"];
}
```

Then assign the value of your textbox to `$pro`

Comment: Sorry for asking,do i need to change  $data['idmsul'] = $result;                 into      
 $data = $_GET["pro"]; ??

Comment: Thank you for taking time to help me,but i don't really understand how u do it...can u help explain a bit to me??